# Changing invalid value to None for INSERT SQL statement but getting "Data Truncated" error

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have a `FLOAT` column in a MySQL table which I am trying to populate using a Python script. Most of the time for the data I'm using the values are valid floats but sometimes they are `"NaN"`. So when inserting into the table I check if the value is `"NaN"` and if so I set it to `None` which, to my understanding, be insert as `NULL` in the table. This is not happening and I'm unsure as to why.

Here is the Python code:

```
for row in zip(plasma_potential_set, floating_potential_set):
        row = [scan_result_id] + list(row)
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if str(row[i]).lower() == "nan":
                row[i] = None
        sql_insert = ('INSERT INTO langmuir_result(scan_data_id, 
                                                   plasma_potential, floating_potential)'
                        'VALUES(%s, "%s", "%s")')
        cursor.execute(sql_insert, row)
    mydb.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Here is the CREATE statement for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE result (result_id INT auto_increment, scan_data_id INT, 
plasma_potential FLOAT, floating_potential FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY (result_id));
```

Here is the error I get:

```
_mysql_exceptions.DataError: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'plasma_potential' at row 1")
```

Here is what the row looks like after I set any invalid values to None:

```
[1, None, 17.4651]
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thank you in advance.

Have looked at this question but mine is slightly different and this one doesn't have an answer: [Unable to use None (NULL) values in python mysql.connector in prepared INSERT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208962/unable-to-use-none-null-values-in-python-mysql-connector-in-prepared-insert-st)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove the `"` in the `VALUES` argument list.
Change your insert statement to:

```
sql_insert = ('INSERT INTO langmuir_result(scan_data_id, plasma_potential, floating_potential)'
                    'VALUES(%s, %s, %s)')
```

and it will work as expected.